# Vue.js: Two way binding value to an input

Tags: html, vue.js, vue-resource

I'm trying to change a header value with binding to a model.

```
<template>
  <input id="token" type="text" v-model='tokenId'>
  <label for="token">Vault Token</label>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        tokenId: this.$http.headers.common['X-Vault-Token']
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Here `tokenId` has the correct value but when I change it from the `input`, it doesn't affect `$http.headers.common['X-Vault-Token']`.

I'm thinking about using `$watch` but how to use it here?

Comment: `tokenId: this.$http.headers.common['X-Vault-Token']` is same as `tokenId : xyz`, changing tokenid wont change `xyz` variable, same thing here.

Answer (score 2):

It should not affect anything except `tokenId` since this is the variable you are using for a model.

Why not

```
<input id="token" type="text" v-model='tokenId' @change="changeToken">
```

and

```
methods: {
  changeToken (e) {
    this.$http.headers.common['X-Vault-Token'] = e.target.value
  }
}
```